# What is the tmux option which causes hiding of status messages?

Tags: shell, command-line, tmux

I have recently started trying out the tool [`tmuxomatic`](https://github.com/oxidane/tmuxomatic) and observed the following behavior which I find undesirable.

In my `.tmux.conf`, I have the following keybinding.

```
bind u   set synchronize-panes
```

When I launch `tmux` normally, if I use the `u` command, it will synchronize panes and also briefly flash a message in the status bar to let me know that my command went through.
However, when I launch `tmux` using `tmuxomatic`, the `u` binding still works, but there's no flash at the bottom.

I skimmed the source code for `tmuxomatic` but did not see anything obvious that would cause the suppress the flashing behavior.

Does anyone know which `tmux` option would cause the status bar to no longer flash on a command, or possibly flash so quickly I cannot see it?

---

I also tried the command `:set synchronize-panes` directly and reproduced the same problem, so it is independent of the keybinding.

The output of version commands.

```
tmux -V
tmux 1.8

tmuxomatic -V
tmuxomatic 2.18
```

Comment: Status bar messages can be sent with `display 'your message here'`, however the keybinding you included doesn't seem to mention `display`. What was the message by the way? Knowing the message, may lead to clues elsewhere if it's not in your individual ~/.tmux.conf.

Comment: @user454038, It is `synchronize-panes  -> on` usually.

Comment: Thanks. Also if you could update the question to include version info. What version of tmux was/are you running that allows you to see this `synchronize-panes -> on` message?  `tmux -V` will tell you this. Also, the output of  `tmuxomatic -V`.

Comment: @user454038, Done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for a while in all the wrong places (tmux source code), I returned to the tmuxomatic source code, and noticed that it had a command line option `-p` which printed out the tmux commands it executed.

Among the commands printed, I saw the following command, which looked promising.

```
/usr/bin/tmux set-option -t tmuxomatic_Test.mux quiet on
```

I ran all the commands manually while excluding this command, and observed that the hiding of status messages no longer occurred, indicating that this was indeed the culprit.